# AJAX jQuery form validation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to check whether entered data is available in database or not. And I am able to check it. But after checking its not showing me the message. But if I put an `alert(1);` after the AJAX call , it works fine.

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Enter Project Name" %><br /><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, :id=> "project_name" %>
    <span id="project_name_error" style="display:none;"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create Project", :onclick => "return validate_project();" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**jquery codes**

```
   <script>
        function validate_project(){
            var check = 0;
            if($("#project_name").val() == '' || ($("#project_name").val() == null)){
                $("#project_name_error").show();
                $("#project_name_error").html("<font color='red' size='1'>Please enter a project name</font>");
                return false;
            }
            if ($("#project_name").val() != ''){
                $.get( "validate/"+$("#project_name").val(), function( data ) {
                    $("#project_name_error").show();
                    $("#project_name_error").html("<font color='red' size='1'>Name Already Exist</font>");          
                    check = 1;
                    return false;
                });
                //alert("1st alert")
                return false;
            }
            //alert("2nd alert")
            return true;
        }

    </script>
```

If I uncomment `1st alert` and `2nd alert` both then I can see that `2nd alert` is coming before the `1st alert`. And my codes works fine. Any help.. Please

Comment: How are you validating in the backend? Just standard database `.exists?` or something?

Comment: And when you uncomment the first and second alerts, you only one one to show, or both? If both, are you sure the conditions will allow the first alert to fire at all?

Comment: if I uncomment the alert then.. second alert comes before 1st alert. And the message `Name Already Exist` is also comes correctly

Comment: It might be the `.get` function taking its time? Have you tried putting `alert("1st alert");` just below the `if` statement?

Comment: ya getting the same...

Comment: humm! Let me look up. It will be handy to have some sort of `break` like in C++

Comment: please let me know... I am in big trouble

Comment: What if you remove last 2 `returns`? It works?

Comment: No one is in "big trouble" LOL Your alerts fire in the wrong order - not going to kill you!

Comment: @zishe.. No , it does't works

Comment: @RichPeck... hahaha But what to do now